# Need help exporting localuser date to a csv... powershell

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv, system-administration

I have written a PowerShell script to grab all local user data for each machine. I need to export this data into a nice looking .csv with the columns ComputerName, ComputerStatus, LocalUserName, LocalUserenabled, and Localuserdescription...

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
$Computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {Enabled -eq $True}
$OutputPath = "$Env:Temp"
$OutputFile = Join-Path $OutputPath "LocalAdminsReport.csv"
Add-Content -Path $OutputFile -Value "ComputerName,ComputerStatus,LocalUserName,LocalUserEnabled,LocalUserDescription"

Foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {
    $ComputerName = $Computer.DNSHostName
    $Connectivity = Test-Connection -Computername $ComputerName -Count 1 -Quiet
    if ($Connectivity) {
        Write-Host "Getting local users from $ComputerName"
        $LocalUsers = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName {Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter  "LocalAccount='True'"}
        ForEach ($LocalUser in $LocalUsers){
            Add-Content -Path $OutputFile -Value $ComputerName, "Online", -Value $LocalUser.Name, -Value $LocalUser.Enabled, -Value $LocalUser.Description
        }
    } else { 
        Write-Host "$ComputerName Status Offline"
        Add-Content -Path $OutputFile -Value $ComputerName, "Offline", $null, $null, $null
    }
}

Write-Host " "
Write-Host "========================================"
Write-Host "Report Path: $OutputFile "
Write-Host "========================================"
```

The current export is putting everything into column 1, I understand it's because of add-content but I really don't know how to do it with export-csv.

Comment: A CSV is just a comma delimited value file. It is a set of strings with commas between them. If you want to manually build one like you're trying to do you need to add content that reflects that. Each line should be a single line connected by commas. Try something like `-value ($computername, "Online", $LocalUser.Name, $LocalUser.Enabled, $LocalUser.Description -join ",")`

Comment: Creating an Object that `Export-Csv` understands is your best option: read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: same results :/

Comment: try $myValues = @("$ComputerName", "Online", "$LocalUser.Name", "$LocalUser.Enabled", "$LocalUser.Description" )
; $myValues | export-csv -Path $OutputFile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, `Add-Content` is not the best tool for creating CSV files.

Try

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"

$OutputFile = Join-Path -Path $env:Temp -ChildPath "LocalAdminsReport.csv"
$Computers  = Get-ADComputer -Filter "Enabled -eq 'True'"  # should be a string

$result = foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {
    $ComputerName = $Computer.DNSHostName
    $Connectivity = Test-Connection -Computername $ComputerName -Count 1 -Quiet

    if ($Connectivity) {
        Write-Host "Getting local users from $ComputerName"
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock {Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter "LocalAccount='True'"} | 
            # output an object
            Select-Object @{Name = 'ComputerName'; Expression = {$ComputerName}},
                          @{Name = 'ComputerStatus'; Expression = {'Online'}},
                          @{Name = 'LocalUserName'; Expression = {$_.Name}},
                          @{Name = 'LocalUserEnabled'; Expression = {!$_.Disabled}},
                          @{Name = 'LocalUserDescription'; Expression = {$_.Description}}
    }
    else { 
        Write-Host "$ComputerName Status Offline"
        # output a similar object for failed computers too
        Select-Object @{Name = 'ComputerName'; Expression = {$ComputerName}},
                      @{Name = 'ComputerStatus'; Expression = {'Offline'}},
                      @{Name = 'LocalUserName'; Expression = {$null}},
                      @{Name = 'LocalUserEnabled'; Expression = {$null}},
                      @{Name = 'LocalUserDescription'; Expression = {$null}}
    }
}

# output to csv file
$result | Export-Csv -Path $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Hey Theo! I tried what you sent but the it didnt export anything...

Comment: @Zack-SysAdmin Sorry.. I neglected to quote the propertynames.. Also took out the `ForEach-Object {...}`, because you don't need that here.